# Unable to hit a break point inside a function in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running my eclipse project in a remote server using maven build. I have set a couple of break points in some of the java files to check the control flow of the code. I am unable to reach the break point inside a function implementation block. I have two break points in a java file like the one shown below:

```
.) public List<classType> functionName(args) throws someException{

.) System.out.println("You should stop here");

//try{
//some more code}
//catch{}

}
```

The two **.)** represents the break points I have set. The system stops at the first one but not at the second. I don't really understand what I am missing here. Looks like the system reaches the block and also performs the desired function, but just does not stop at the break point.

PS: I execute the project in command prompt by giving mvn install command and turn on the debug mode to look for the flow.

Comment: could it be that an exception is thrown before you reach the second breakpoint?

Comment: I thought that could be a reason, so, I tried to access the code related to that exception, but I got a message in eclipse stating that the source not found. I don't know how to find the source for the exception.

Comment: If you can hit the first breakpoint at the start of the method you could try stepping through the program from there. If an exception is thrown you will see exactly where.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am hoping for now. But, the second break point is not getting hit. The first line inside the function is not getting detected. Not really sure what to do here

Comment: One thing I noticed is that System should have a capital S, but that would cause a compilation error rather than any issues at runtime

Comment: That is a typo. The control does not reach that point. That is the issue

Comment: No worries, just something that caught my eye. Can you post the whole class? Will be easier to spot any potential exceptions

Comment: I am not supposed to expose any code. That is why I posted a generic code. Anyways, I will try to include more information if possible

Comment: No problem. I would look into Jim's answer below. It's very common using eclipse and maven for there to be some discrepancies in the compiled versions of your source and what's in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, failure to hit a remote breakpoint means that the compiled code on the remote system is not exactly the same version as the source code you are seeing in your Eclipse session.  Breakpoints are set by line number and if the line numbers don't match the breakpoint could point to a line number that is not executable (i.e. not a candidate for a breakpoint) on the remote system.  In that case the breakpoint would not be set and would appear to be skipped.

You must ensure that the code running on the remote was compiled from exactly the same source as you are seeing in your local Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What you are saying makes sense to me. I will make sure that the code in the remote system and my local machine are the same before executing it again.

Comment: Hey Jim, could you tell me how to update the code a remote system runs to match the code in the local machine? I wiped out my project and ran from the beginning and got the control stop at the break point, but after an update to the code, I am having the same problem.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of what we can do here. You need to find out the process by which the remote system is deployed, and figure out what version (in your source control system) was built and deployed.  If you are the one doing the deployment this should be easy.  If someone else does the deployment you'll have to ask them.