# not stopping at breakpoint Intellij 15.02 or 14.1.4 now but worked earlier

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am unable to debug as the breakpoints are skipped. It was working earlier but not since a few days. Not sure what might have happened. I updated from Intellij 14.1.4 to 15.02 but still the issue exists. The way I am running/debugging the test code is I created a Maven configuration in Intellij by providing the working directory and the command line `clean install test -DforkCount=0`

- java version "1.8.0_51" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_51-b16) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
- Intellij 14.1.4, 15.02
- OS X 10.10.4
- Apache Maven 3.3.3
- using maven surefire plugin

`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <!-- reportng -->
                    <properties>
                        <!--Adding for reportng begin-->
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                        </property>
                        <!--Adding for reportng end-->
                    </properties>
                    <!-- end of reportng -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <config>${test.config}</config>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

- pom xml entry for Testng

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
>         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
>         <version>6.9.6</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

I am debugging locally only.
The tests that I would like to debug are in suite.xml and I am using TestNG too. 
I am able to run by right clicking and running/debugging TestNG test cases but I would also like to do the debug using the maven configuration though I am able to run fine using maven configuration.

Just a note:
Debugging using right click on the class file (typically done for TestNG test case e.t.c) is different from debugging by clicking on the top selecting the desired configuration (in my case I used to choose the created Maven configuration)

Comment: Are you debugging locally or remotely deployed in a server?

Comment: Still working for me and I'm using all the same versions.  Maybe try a File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: Potential duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/34008198  but maybe not close enough to dup-hammer.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am debugging only locally.

Comment: @EGHM I have tried File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart  but no luck

Answer (score 3):

Breakpoints only work if you're a) running locally through intellij, or b) you're using intellij as a remote debugger connecting to another jvm. If you're using maven to run your unit tests then it's unlikely that you're going to be able to debug them in intellij.

Try running your tests in IntelliJ by right clicking on the test folder and selecting the "Debug tests in..." option. This should hit your breakpoints just fine.

Maven is used to allow you to share your project with other developers, and with CI/CD tools like Jenkins and TeamCity. It's not generally used as part of the personal development process in the way you're describing. Usually we just run our code through the IDE until its ready, then we push it to a central repo, which triggers CI to use maven to build the software and run the tests in order to confirm that we haven't broken anything.

Comment: I got the it working by right click and run but I would still like to use the Maven configuration to run the tests.

Comment: by the way  I was able to debug using the maven configuration earlier.